# Sockets python client

Tags: python, sockets

I currently have this code

```
import socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 1111
address=(ip,port)
server.bind(address)
server.listen(1)
print("Started listening on", ip, ":", port)
client.addr=server.accept()
while True:
      data = client.recv(1024)
      print("received",data, "from the client")
      print("Processing data")
      if(data=="Hello server"):
          client.send("hello client")
          print("Processing done")
      elif(data=="disconnect"):
          client.send("goodbye")
          client.close()
          break
      else:
          client.send("Invalid data")
          print("invalid data")
```

However i get this error message: NameError: name 'client' is not defined.
But why?

Comment: It's `client, addr = server.accept()` (_comma_ (`,`), not _dot_ (`.`) between `client` and `addr`).

Comment: Thank you for the fast respons!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is devoted to the fact that the function server.accept() return two values, the socket itself and the address. Therefore being accepted this way:

```
client, addr = server.accept()
```

would allow what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the fast respons!

Comment: glad I could help :)